# Apache Ant: Can I search all files for a specific regex and then print the matches to a file?

Tags: regex, ant, build

In an Ant build.xml, I would like to be able to find any matches in all .html files using the following regex:

```
("|')((?!http://|#|mailto:|&|/)([^#\n\s\."])+?\.([^#\n\s"])+?)\1
```

Then, I want to list those matches of \2 in a file.  Is this possible?

Final result, thanks to @bakoyaro:

```
    <echo message="Collecting appcache files" />
    <concat destFile="your_output_file">
        <fileset dir="./${dir.publish}">
            <include name="**/*.html"/>
        </fileset>
        <filterchain>
            <linecontainsregexp>
                <regexp pattern="(.)*?(&quot;|')((?!http://|\?|#|mailto:|\1)([^#\n\s\.&quot;'?])+?\.([^#\n\s&quot;'?])+?)\2" />
            </linecontainsregexp>
            <tokenfilter>
                <replaceregex pattern="(.)*?(&quot;|')((?!http://|\?|#|mailto:|\1)([^#\n\s\.&quot;'?])+?\.([^#\n\s&quot;'?])+?)\2" flags="g" replace="\1\2\3\2${line.separator}" />
            </tokenfilter>
            <linecontainsregexp>
                <regexp pattern="(.)*?(&quot;|')((?!http://|\?|#|mailto:|\1)([^#\n\s\.&quot;'?])+?\.([^#\n\s&quot;'?])+?)\2" />
            </linecontainsregexp>
            <tokenfilter>
                <replaceregex pattern="(.)*?(&quot;|')((?!http://|\?|#|mailto:|\1)([^#\n\s\.&quot;'?])+?\.([^#\n\s&quot;'?])+?)\2" flags="g" replace="\3" />
            </tokenfilter>
            <linecontainsregexp>
                <regexp pattern="((?!http://|\?|#|mailto:|\1)([^#\n\s\.&quot;'?])+?\.([^#\n\s&quot;'?])+?)" />
            </linecontainsregexp>
        </filterchain>
    </concat>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this using the [Concat](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/concat.html) task with a nested [FilterChain](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html).

Something like this:

```
<concat destFile="your_output_file">
    <fileset dir="WebContent">
        <include name="**/*.html"/>
    </fileset>
    <filterchain>
        <linecontainsregexp>
            <regexp pattern="your_pattern_to_match" />
        </linecontainsregexp>
        <tokenfilter>
            <replaceregex pattern="your_pattern_to_extract" replace="output_required" />
        </tokenfilter>
    </filterchain>
</concat>
```

Comment: This will actually "get" the matched tokens so I can output them?

Comment: This will output the matches to the destFile specified in the concat task. Alternatively, if you use concat without a destFile attribute, it will output to the console. Looks like it was useful for you, as your solution used all the elements: concat, filterchain, linecontainsregexp, tokenfilter.

Comment: Yes, and apparently I checked the wrong answer.  I really hate how SO moves them all around.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a snippet that may help, it will create a .zip file containing any of the files that match your regex. I use it to examine my builds to ensure that all of the ant tokens were replaced.

```
<zip destfile="${your_file_name}" update="true" whenempty="skip">
            <fileset dir="${your_search_directory}">
                    <!-- your file pattern -->
                    <include name="**/*.html" />
                    <!-- this will destroy an executable file. best to exclude them -->
                <exclude name="**/*.jar" />
                <containsregexp expression="your_regex_to_match" />
            </fileset>
        </zip>
```

Comment: I'm not looking to replace--only collect the tokens and place the tokens in a text file.

Comment: With a few modifications, this worked great!  Thanks SO much for your expertise.  This has really gotten me more interested in Ant.